# How to: CSS border with a kite-shape in the middle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to achive a border that is a simple line, but in the middle of it there is a kite-shape square, some thing like this:

[image]

but I would prefer not using an image border since if the div is streched the "kite" looks streched as well, I want the kite it self to be of fixed size (say 10px from the left edge to the right) and the rest is a straight line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Since you did not make a whole lot of effort in your question by at least identifying what you have tried, I will push it back on you to do the research (that is how you learn). I will however point you in the right direction: Check out the border-image property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Read through the details, and if you are still not able to successfully implement, then update your question with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with css [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and `:before` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  top: 100px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #FF0000;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="kite-separator"><span class="kite-center"></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.kite-separator  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color:#cb0009;
  position:relative;
}
.kite-center {
  display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #cb0009;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -3px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/azq2gcqq/

Comment: This works nice as an option for an HR style, but from the question, I gather that he is looking for a border in that style, not a horizontal rule with a diamond.  border-image would be a more versatile option here.

Comment: Instead of a negative margin left, i would go with a translateY(-50%), so if you wanna change dimension of the kite you won't have to change the margin too

Comment: @MattiaNocerino Thanks for the tip. I never tried that but looks like a neat little trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one square, i would go with the pseudo element ::after like this  https://jsfiddle.net/6fLuagsv/

```
.class-with-border{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #c00;
  width: 100px;
}

.class-with-border::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #c00;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

if you need one square per side, just insert in the container 4 elements and adjust them as you want.